# An error occurred while updating the entries when SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I write application using Entity Framework, I write any code in "ButtonSave" like thís:

```
_objEntities = new PCApp_TaxitechEntities();
contact objModel = new contact();
objModel.Name = customerName;
objModel.Phone = PhoneNumber;
_objEntities.contacts.Add(objModel);
int Result = _objEntities.SaveChanges();
```

This throws exception in line:

`int Result = _objEntities.SaveChanges();`

With message like:

> An error occurred while updating the entries: {"Invalid object name 'dbo.contact'."}

Here my connectionString:

`<connectionStrings>
     <add name="PCApp_TaxitechEntities" 
          connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PCApp_Taxitech;
          User ID=sa;Password="/>
</connectionStrings>`

Of courses, In SQL Server, I have database `PCApp_Taxitech`.

I don't know when call `SaveChanges()` method this application throw exception.

Comment: do you have  a table called contact in that database ?

Comment: how you configured your DbSet ?

Comment: @VănLộc your table is called `contacts` (plural), but EF is trying to write to a table called `contact` (singular). Check your EDMX and make sure the correct table is referenced.

Comment: A developer hand over a project after his left my company. But database was lost, I see .edmx file and `Generate database from model`. I change `connectionString`.

Comment: Well, I don't know your project, haven't seen your edmx file or how you created your database... but the error message vs your screenshot (which is what I've seen) is pretty clear: EF is trying to write to `dbo.contact`, your table is called `dbo.contacts` (not `contact`), hence the error. Your error is unrelated to the code you posted (other than calling `SaveChanges`) and to your connection string, as long as it's connecting to that database

Comment: I'll put it as an answer if that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that somehow your database table is called `contacts` (plural), while Entity Framework is trying to write to a table called `contact` (singular).

The easy solution would be to just rename the table, but if you have generated your database from your EDMX, it'd be wise to revise it and see where it may have pluralized the database table name, but not the mapped table name (which sounds pretty weird).